# java getString("SQL database area") - tokenize it?

Tags: java, sql, tokenize, pull

Currently I'm pulling data out of SQL database table unfortunately one specific column contains more than one value (specifically an address). So I'm trying to .append this address data into a textArea of my program but I need to break the lines there so I figured I might try to tokenize it and .append(.nextToken + "\n") unless there is a better way to do it?

Here's some of my tryhard stuff

```
 try {
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

            if (rs.next()) {
                String addressLine = rs.getString("adres");
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(addressLine);
                String token = st.nextToken();
                dbNameField.setText(rs.getString("name"));
                dbNazwiskoField.setText(rs.getString("surname"));
                dbAgeField.setText(""+rs.getInt("age"));
                rs.getInt("id");
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                dbAddressField.append(token+ "\n");
                }

            }
```

except it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class, so there is no problem in using it (as in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)), but it is not recommended.

A simpler solution recommended by JavaDoc is to use [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) `split(String regex)` method and iterate over the returned array using foreach cycle.

One more detail - do not use `builder.append(token + "\n")`, there is a cleaner aproach: `builder.append(token).append(System.lineSeparator())`.

Using `\n` is platform dependent as it doesn't work on unix-based systems.

Using `String` concatenation can also slow your program if the compiler doesn't optimize it correctly. Especially if you have a `StringBuilder` ready :)

Comment: Finally made it, love you sir.